# How to fix syntax error while defining a class?

Tags: syntax-error, puppet

I'm trying to install the module located at https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mongodb. What I don't seem to understand is where to place

```
class mongodb {
  enable_10gen => true,
}
```

in their Usage and installation instructions.

I've already cloned the repo and put it in `/etc/puppet/modules/mongodb`.

If I put that in my main site.pp file, I get a syntax error:

> Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '=>';
>   expected '}' at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:8

Line 8 is in reference to the enable_10gen line.

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong syntax for a parametrised class. The correct syntax is:

```
class{'mongodb':
    enable_10gen => true,
}
```